# problem converting 4-bytes array to float in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, byte

I'm using C# and reading bytes array from some controller and converting them to their types. all values (int,string) OK except the float values.
The value that suppose to get is 533174.1.
but when reading the array

```
byteArr[0]=2
byteArr[1]=73
byteArr[2]=98
byteArr[3]=43
```

getting some gibberish value.
I used the `System.BitConverter.ToDouble(bytesArr,0)` and other methods without success.
please help.
Thanks,
Igal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your bytes are coming out word-swapped. This function should convert your byte array to floats properly:

```
static float ToFloat(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] newArray = new[] { input[2], input[3], input[0], input[1] };
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(newArray, 0);
}

ToFloat(new byte[]{2,73,98,43}) == 533174.1
```

Answer (score 4):

1. How about endianess? Have you tried reversing the word order? In windows, 533174.1 is 98, 43, 2, 73.
2. 4 bytes are a single (ToSingle), not double.

Comment: A float is not a double.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a byte array with four positions to float, BitConverter.ToSingle should be used, this function reads four positions within the array used, for example:

```
var input = new byte[]{103, 242, 50, 67};
var floatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 0);
```

floatValue = 178.946884

The BitConverter.ToSingle method receives two parameters: the byte array and the position where it will start taking the values.

We can also take an array with greater length and define where to start the conversions

```
var secondInput = new byte[]{103, 242, 50, 67, 227, 55, 179, 67};
var firtsFloatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 0);
var secondFloatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 4);
```

firtsFloatValue = 178.946884

secondFloatValue  = 358.4366

Finally to obtain the value 533174.1 starting from [98, 43, 2, 73] we must use

```
var input = new byte[]{98, 43, 2, 73};
var floatValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 0);
```

floatValue = 533174.1

Comment: Dude you had the correct code in the sample, but you said "Convert" twice instead of bitconverter.  It caused problems.