# C# : how to convert char array into float

Tags: c#, arrays, char, data-conversion

I have a byte array of four bytes which contains the byts of a FLOAT values.
For example

array[0]=0x1F

array[1]=0x05

array[2]=0x01

array[3]=0x42

this should be 0x4201051f, which means 32.255 value.

Do you have any suggestion on how to group the array and save the value in a float data?

Thank you

Comment: a .net `char` is 16-bit, and does not represent a  byte. So, do you have a char-array or a byte-array?

Comment: sorry, I meant a byte array. my fault. I'll correct it immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo), the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301623/problem-converting-4-bytes-array-to-float-in-c-sharp) provides the answer:

```
var input = new byte[] { 0x1F, 0x05, 0x01, 0x42 };
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 0)); // Outputs 32.255
```